# How to use memcached in Grails

Tags: grails, memcached

I am a beginner of Grails.
I'd like to use memcached in Grails, I have tried with reference to the following.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-memcached2/index.html

Download the jar, I put the lib folder the jar.
Then run-app, I found the error.

Error Message

> /grails-app/services/MemcachedService.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class net.spy.memcached.AddrUtil
>
> @ Line 1, column 1.
>
> import net.spy.memcached.AddrUtil
>     ^
>
> /grails-app/services/MemcachedService.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient
>
> @ Line 2, column 1.
>
> import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient
>     ^
>
> 2 errors

I have written on the page that I referred to, and just put the lib folder the jar.

I wonder that must be set in addition to it?

Please help me.

Grails version: 2.1.2

spymemcached version: 2.8.4

OS: CentOS

Comment: do a **grails war** and check (see its contents) whether the war that is generated contains the spymemcached-2.8.4.jar in the lib folder. Also check if you have downloaded the correct jar (not the javadocs or sources)

Answer (score 8):

You're better off adding a dependency in BuildConfig.groovy. Let Grails download it once for you and cache it so you can use it in multiple projects.

Add http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/ as a custom repository:

```
repositories {
   grailsPlugins()
   grailsHome()
   grailsCentral()

   mavenRepo 'http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/'
}
```

and then add the dependency for spymemcached:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'spy:spymemcached:2.8.9'
}
```

If you do need to use a jar file (e.g. if it's not available in a public repo) put it in the `lib` directory but you need to run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` to get the file recognized and added to the application's dependencies.

Comment: Hello Burt.I was able to solve the problem thanks to your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @ tnnsst35 : Please accept the answer; upvote if you like. It will help you get more help later.

Comment: I tried to use this solution but I get an error while trying to download the pom: "Could not transfer artifact spy:spymemcached:zip:2.8.9 from/to repository.jboss.com/maven2/ (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/): Forbidden (403)" Any ideas?